# Updating Magento 2 product attribute, Import Add/Update feature always create a duplicate new item, instead of updating

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, importexport, import-products

i'm trying to update a custom product attribute called is_eol, but when i use the system->data transfer->import -> import behavior (add/update), it always created a duplicate item with same sku number.

for example, my csv file looks like:

sku, is_eol
abc, eol

where sku:abc is already exist in the catalog.

Comment: I assume that you exported your current products (which would have an empty attribute field) then added the one piece of data before importing everything back into Magento?

Comment: I just create an csv, and created two columns (sku, is_eol) and add it's value, then import. This is how I did for magento 1. Do I have the exported all the attributes and reimport them back ( with only adjusted the one attribute)? thanks.

Comment: Yes I would export the product/s that you are interested in.  Depending on how you have set up the attribute it may need to be modified in the additional attributes string column and not just added to its own individual column.  You will see what i mean when you do an export